# Errors compile using mraa library with Eclipse IDE

Tags: pi-3, toolchain

I'm new to Eclipse IDE. I'm currently getting started with gpio library for Raspberry Pi 3 which is mraa on Eclipse IDE as well as a cross - compiler for  in Windows Operating System. Errors I've got while trying an example "hellomraa" from mraa library folder being depicted in attached screenshot. Those are

> libmraa.so: undefined reference to 'fcntl@GLIBC_2.28'
>
> libmraa.so: undefined reference to 'glob@GLIBC_2.27'

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- mraa library's link: https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa
- I'm using Windows toolchain for Raspberry Pi GCC 4.6.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: User @tmt, so you are cross compiling MRAA on Windows.  In case you could not find help from the Windows guys, perhaps you can try Rpi MRAA, but that requires SWIG.  I once tried SWIG and found it a bit tedious to do the compiling stuff - 

https://www.ics.com/blog/getting-started-mraa-raspberry-pi

Comment: @tlfong. Thanks for replying. I also tried to build example project on terminal before and it worked successfully. But using an IDE on Windows is a convenient way to build an executable from a host platform (what I'm currently using is Windows laptop) to another platform (Raspberry Pi). Before using mraa for cross - compiler, I tried wiringPi and it also worked. So moving on to mraa and I set all the parameters in project options all the same as the project using wiringPi on Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Can you show the problem tab and add a picture of the code where the error occur (if there is) I have this error the whole time when in Cross-Compile

Comment: What have you put in the includes in Cross GCC Compiler ?

Comment: @Arnaud: I've edited my post. You may see it now

Comment: I'm sorry I have the same thing at my side and it works i don't know what to do for you

Comment: @Arnaud: Are you using mraa library?

Comment: No but it should behave the same, I've tried for one week to make disappear theses errors with @GLIBC something. And what you've already done solved the problem every time…
What i'm sure is that you have a problem with eclipse, we miss something that should be put in order for it to work..
What's your Eclipse Version ? I know there is some bug with older ones

Comment: @Arnaud: Kind of old version, that is Juno Service Release 2

Comment: Okay, if you can try the last CDT, I run on 2019-03. It works flawlessly, and the remote debug works. If you ever solve your problem but you have connection problem to remote debug, switch version, there are some BIG bugs for remote debug in old version.

Comment: @Arnaud: Thank you so much for your help. I'll try it now and review it to you.

Comment: @Arnaud: Hi. I've tried Eclipse 2019 - 06 and got the same errors. I'm installing the 2019 - 03 one and giving it a try :(

Comment: @tmt Okay, crossing fingers ! If it still don't work maybe try redo the whole project from zero… But now it's kind of black magic….

Comment: @Arnaud: Okay, if you have spare time, you could give it a try with the mraa library as you are doing with wiringPi like I did. Maybe you could find something new.
Updated: The same old days :(

Comment: Okay, I give it a try i will tell you. Where do you find the binaries you are using ? ( I mean on the GitHub)

Comment: @Arnaud: Do you mean the .so file (shared library)?

Comment: @Arnaud: how are you doing?

Comment: @Arnaud: updated. I've tried to deploy another version of installed library (.so file, ver 1.7.0) and it completely works rather than using the version that I used (ver 2.0.0) which I get by installing directly on Raspberry Pi following this instruction [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=213363)

So I think the problem is between the version of shared library and the toolchain.

Comment: Okay, it's rather weird... there must me something missing in the 1.7.0 version...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the library in the settings of your project.

Let me explain you,

- **right click** on **hellomraa**, then go in **properties**
- In **C/C++ Build** select **settings**
- Then in **Tool Settings** tab go under **Cross GCC Linker** then **Libraries**
- Then add your library, with the green + you just type *mraa* **not the lib prefix !** There is something to do it the library is .so you just type the name, if it is .a you have to add : before the library name
- You also have to add the path to the library, in your case it is in your workspace

[image: This should help you with an example]

You may have to add your include path in Eclipse too, just go under **inclues** and put the path to your workspace where your mrra.h is.

**Depending on which Eclipse version you are working on, you may have big trouble setting up a Cross-compilation / remote debug environment. I tried many version of Eclipse and only the last 2019-03 CDT version worked flawlessly for me…**

Comment: I also did it. I've edited my question

Comment: Have you done it for the includes too ?